# Why append list is slower in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

During testing I find out in the following, MP method run a bit slower

```
def eat_time(j):
    result = []
    for j in range(10**4):
        a = 0
        for i in range(1000):
            a += 101
            result.append(a)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #MP method
    t = time.time()
    pool = Pool()
    result = []
    data = pool.map(eat_time, [i for i in range(5)])
    for d in data:
        result += d
    print(time.time()-t) #11s for my computer

    #Normal method
    t = time.time()
    integers = []
    for i in range(5):
        integers += eat_time(i)
    print(time.time()-t) #8s for my computer
```

However, if I don't require it to aggregate the data by changing `eat_time()` to

```
def eat_time(j):
    result = []
    for j in range(10**4):
        a = 0
        for i in range(1000):
            a += 101
            #result.append(a)
    return result
```

The MP time is much faster and now for my computer just run **3s**, while normal method still take **8s**. **(As expected)**

It looks strange to me as `result` is declared individually in `method`, I don't expect appending completely ruin the MP.

May I know is there a correct way to do this? And why MP is slower when append involved?

---

**Edited for comment**

Thx for @torek and @akhavro clarify the point.

Yes, I understand creating process take times, that's why the problem raised.

Actually the original code put the for-loop outside and call the simple method again and again, it is a bit faster over normal method in significantly many task (my case more than 10**6 calls).

Therefore I change to put code inside and make the method a bit more complicated. By moving `for j in range(10**4):` this line into `eat_time()`.

But it seems making the code complicated causes communication lag due to larger data size.

So, probably the answer is no way to solve it.

Comment: What's the Python version?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal, I tested in 2.7, 3.7, both results are same.

Comment: When you return a result that is a very large list, you are sending a LOT of data back from the child (worker) process to the parent. This will take significant time—probably about as long as it took to generate the list.

Comment: @torek, do you mean the only way to make it right is putting the `for-loop` outside the `eat_time()` method?

Comment: You could send the result back via some other method, e.g., a shared-memory array, which might be faster. But in general, whenever you use a process pool, you should account for communications overhead: how long will it take to send work requests, and how long will it take to send results back? If the communications time exceeds the work time, there's little point in trying to shift the workload.

Comment: Also processes take a long time to be created, because each one of them needs to allocate it's own memory and to create it's own environment (declared variables). If the task itself (in this case appending) is not long enough, multiprocessing will take more time that a simple sequential execution.

Comment: @akhavro: true, though the `pool` amortizes the startup cost over multiple calls (assuming you make a lot of calls). Note that creating a new process is also much quicker on Unix-like systems, which don't have as much overhead as Windows.

Comment: @torek, as the edited part state, I think the conclusion is no solution for this right?

Comment: @MatrixTai Is your function `eat_time()` correct? You pass it the parameter `j`, but that value never gets used inside the function, because you override that variable by using `for j in range(10**4):`

Comment: Note that you're appending `10**4` (10000) copies of 1000 numbers, hence returning a list of ten million values.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but would using Multi-threading instead of Multi-processing help at all? In other words, can Multi-threading speed up the whole process for this specific problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not append that causes your slowness but returning the result with appended elements. You can test it by changing your code to do the append but return only the first few elements of your result.  Now it should work much faster again.

When you return your result from a `Pool` worker, this is in practice implemented as a queue from multiprocessing. It works but it is not a miracle performer, definitely much slower than just manipulating in-memory structures. When you return a lot of data, the queue needs to transmit a lot.

There is no easy workaround. You could try shared memory but I do not personally like it due to added complexity. The better way would be to redesign your application so that it does not need to transmit a lot of data between processes. For example, would it be possible to process data in your worker further so that you do not need to return it all but only a processed subset?